# What are the most critical settings to tweak when setting up a new Windows Vista machine?

Tags: windows-vista

**Possible Duplicate**

[Which Windows Tweaks Do You Use And They Actually Work](https://superuser.com/questions/3864/which-windows-tweaks-do-you-use-and-they-actually-work)

You've bought a new system. You install vanilla Windows Vista on the machine. What are the most important settings to tweak before using the system and why? Turn off User Account Control (UAC)? Make every folder open in detailed view? Change the background? Change certain services and autoruns?

Comment: This is probably already covered here http://superuser.com/questions/3864/which-windows-tweaks-do-you-use-and-they-actually-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToFreeingUpDiskSpaceUnderWindowsVista.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- Turn of delete confirmation for Recycle Bin (Recycle Bin -> Properties -> Display delete confirmation dialog)
- Show Hidden Files and Folders (Explorer -> (Alt) Tools -> Folder Options -> View -> Show hidden files and folders
- Turn of Hide extensions for known file types while you're there.
- I turn off UAC, but I wouldn't recommend it for everyone
- Turn off Sidebar

Answer (score 0):

IMO, switch off Aero. Both times I've had a new Vista machine I've gone around switching off the little pointless gimmick features before unearthing the master switch. Can't remember where it is.